# How to add a method to devise base controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to add a method to Devise base controller, i.e DeviseController, so that it is available to all Devise inherited controllers like Registrations, Sessions etc. The aim is to use it in before filter for all devise controllers only.

But if I attempt to add any method via,

```
DeviseController < ApplicationController

  protected

  def my_method
    # logic
  end
end
```

and add this file as app/controllers/devise_controller.rb, I encounter "**undefined method require_no_authentication**" error in the **RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController**.

Any idea how to overcome this issue?